# How did Pytorch process images in ImageNet when training resnet pretrained models in torchvision.models.resnet34?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, resnet, torchvision, imagenet

I downloaded the pretrained parameters of resnet34 in `torchvision.models` and put them to a tensorflow1.X network, but just get 58% accurary testing on the ImageNet2015 Validation set (50,000 picture).

I guess it may be caused by the different precessing method to the data set. The Validation I am using is in TFRecord format processed by my friend.

So I am wondering how Pytorch process images of ImageNet when training resnet34 pretrained models? Turn RGB to BGR? Scale pictures values to 0--1?

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html):

> All pre-trained models expect input images normalized in the same way, i.e. mini-batches of 3-channel RGB images of shape (3 x H x W), where H and W are expected to be at least 224. The images have to be loaded in to a range of [0, 1] and then normalized using `mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]` and `std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]`. You can use the following transform to normalize:
>
> ````
> normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
>                                  std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])```
> ````

The documentation links [this example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/42e5b996718797e45c46a25c55b031e6768f8440/imagenet/main.py#L89-L101) for preprocessing ImageNet data.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! I print and check the TF_record images, and found that the values are between -1 to 1, but I still don't know how tensorflow processing Imagnet to get this format, do you have any ideal?

Comment: Please open a new question and provide the code used to load ImageNet as well as the necessary details regarding your specific TFRecords implementation.